# Does Microsoft Dynamics CRM have a built in ability to recognize bar codes?

Tags: dynamics-crm, barcode, barcode-scanner

At my shop we are managing a campaign with printed materials.  These printed materials have bar codes.  We are trying to figure out the best way to scan these bar codes into Dynamics CRM.

Is there a built in way for Microsoft Dynamics CRM to recognize bar codes?  Or is there a 3rd party solution for this?

I have spoken with KwikTag's folks but they don't seem very confident about their product's integration with CRM.

In other words, is there something built in or a 3rd party tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short version: ***no***

There is no barcode scanning functionality in Dynamics CRM. However most (or all - I'm not sure on that) barcode scanners work like keyboards, which means that the scanned data is typed like you've typed it on a keyboard. The software cannot decide wether the source of the input is the scanner or the keyboard. Therefore it should be no problem to include the barcode data as a custom attribute.

Comment: Just to extend this... you would basically hold the UPC (barcode number) in a text field (you would probably want to add some validations here) and that way if you wanted to enter/validate a barcode, you simply use the scanner instead of typing. The ones I have worked with before simply "type for you"

Comment: @devin: correct. As most integrations of scanners only read the code for you. The post processing (like validation) should be done by the application itself. So as long as rsteckly doesn't describe his requirements in more details, it is all we could say.